# Displaying picture, name and description in a listView android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

Im trying to display some information from my Items[] in a listview, the information is retrived from database. what I want to display is a picture, name and description. note that the picture is retrived in base64 string so I have to convert it before sending data.

I tried this:

```
 for(int x=0;x<items.length;x++) {
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(items[x].Picture, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Itemlist.this, (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) listView, R.layout.layout, new String[]{items[x].Name, items[x].Description}, new int[]{R.id.move_title, R.id.move_rating});
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
```

but I got this error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

this is the activity layout:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ffffff"

>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and the list layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/move_poster"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"


    />

<View

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/move_poster"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/move_poster"
    android:layout_below="@+id/move_poster">
</View>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/move_title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/move_poster"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/move_rating"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/move_title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/move_poster"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/move_poster"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/move_poster" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the whole activity class:

```
public class Itemlist extends ListActivity {

private Handler mHandler= new Handler();
Item[] items;
ListView listView;
MoveAdapter adapter;
TextView tv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_itemlist);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    listView=getListView();
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String[] params= new String[]{"192.168.1.11:90"};
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);
}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    public String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/GetAllItems";
    public String OPERATION_NAME ="GetAllItems";
    public String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE ="http://tempuri.org/";
    public String SOAP_ADDRESS;
    private SoapObject request;
    private HttpTransportSE httpTransport;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop;
    Object response= null;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://" + params[0] + "/myWebService2.asmx";
        request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);


        envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelop.dotNet = true;
        envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        try {

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelop);

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelop.getResponse();
            items = new Item[response.getPropertyCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                SoapObject pii = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);
                Item item = new Item();
                item.Name = pii.getProperty(0).toString();
                item.Description = pii.getProperty(1).toString();
                item.Picture = pii.getProperty(2).toString();
                item.ID = Integer.parseInt(pii.getProperty(3).toString());
                items[i] = item;
            }


        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
            soapFault.printStackTrace();
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Done";        }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                tv.setText(result);
                for(int x=0;x<items.length;x++) {
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(items[x].Picture, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Itemlist.this, (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) listView, R.layout.layout, new String[]{items[x].Name, items[x].Description}, new int[]{R.id.move_title, R.id.move_rating});
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

also I don't know how to send the bitmap format of the picture to the adapter, because it only takes Strings.

can someone please help me displaying the listview of images, name and description?

Comment: `(List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) listView` ...  Does `ListView` implements `List` interface? *can someone please help me displaying the listview of images, name and description?* it is not possible - you don't even know java's basics

Comment: @Selvin instead of this I was putting items, but the android studio said that is wrong and correct it like this!

Comment: *but the android studio said that is wrong and correct it like this!* FSM save us! becuse android studio can't fix completely nones ... SimpleAdapter constructor  expects `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>`  instance there .... and you put `ListView` instance there ...

Comment: @Selvin I told you I was putting my list which is items and the android studio auto corrected like this!

Comment: also, you know that you are creating and setting new instance of Adapter in every loop's pass?

Comment: @Selvin there is no need to be aggressive and offensive, OP is trying to solve the problem by asking a question, so if you can help go ahead, if you can't just try to be nice :)

Comment: @Selvin thank you so much for encouraging me to get better by your beautiful helpful words!!! if you are an AWSOME expert that knows EVERYTHING! why cant you simply help beginners in a better way?!

Comment: @Lama you are casting a listView object to List which is not correct and will never work for you, try to make a `List` or `ArrayList` of `Item` and pass it to the adapter. move the decoding work inside the adapter, or add `Bitmap` member for class `Item` and set it in the `for` loop and use it in the adapter

Comment: @Yazan THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @Yazan thanks a lot !! I will try it now :)

Comment: *List or ArrayList of Item*  @Yazan you are wrong ... SimpleAdapter expects List of Map<String, ?> ... also `new String[]{items[x].Name, items[x].Description}` it doesn't make sens ... it expects (from the docs) *A list of **column names** that will be added to the Map associated with each item*

Comment: @Selvin here you go being helpful, i did not notice OP used SimpleAdapter, see, it's not hard to be nice :)

Comment: @Lama thats right you need to use custom adapter `ArrayAdapter` why don't you google it and i will post a good answer if you can't find out, i will need few hours to be home, i will check it then :) good luck

Comment: @Yazan Yes please post an answer whenever you can, and I will also search about it now. Take your time. And I'm really thankful for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i think i have some time to do it now,
here we go.

**but first you need to read and learn Custom adapter for listView**

you can google it and understand how it works,
then come back to this answer.
[here you can findsome good sample for a custom adapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) 
you really need to read and understand it.

now, some code changes for your's

1- modify your `Item` class to have a Bitmap Member

```
public Bitmap bitmap;
```

adding setter and getter is better. but you can make it public and access it directly

2- **[Optional]** in `Itemlist` activity, declare `Arraylist` instead of `array`
you will learn more about this when you search for custom adapter, as you can pass data as `Array` or as `List`

```
private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList();
```

3- modify the `for` loop as following: (assuming you did not changed to arrayList and still use array[])

```
for(int x=0;x<items.length;x++) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(items[x].Picture, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    items[x].bitmap = decodedByte;
}//for loop end
```

4- declare adapter (instance of your Custom Adapter), and assign it to the listView

```
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(ItemsList.this, R.layout.list_row, items);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

now in your adapter's `getView()` method, you can use the memebrs (name, desc, bitmap) to populate the custom layout of each row

that's it.

P.S: this code is not all compiled, and may contain some typos, 
it's just to guide you through the process.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Did it and worked as I want! Really thank you so much for your time and help! And thanks to you now I understand it very good :)

Comment: Waiting for his next question... It will be I'm getting oomexception, what to do...